# create data frame with key value pair in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

As I am new to scala need to convert following code in scala which i written in python

```
Dict={"test1":"date","test2":"string"}

for x in Dict.keys():
    column= x
    type = Dict[x]
    print (column)
    print (type)
```

output

```
test1
date
test2
string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

> Map(collection of key/value pairs)

in **Scala**.   See  [Scala Maps](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_maps.htm)

```
 val testMap  = Map("test1" -> "Date", "test2" -> "String" )
```

**Iterate over Key/Value pairs**

```
 for ((key,value) <- testMap) println(s"key: $value, value: $value\n")
```

**Conversion to DF**

```
val df = testMap.toSeq.toDF("name", "dataType")
df.show()
```